# Need to test login in html page from my localhost to external server using apache proxy in virtual host

Tags: apache, proxy

I am trying to test a login form in an html page on my local machine. The login request is posted to an external web server. The external server will only accept requests that originate from its domain. I therefore need to configure apache to make a request from my local domain appear to originate from the external server's domain. I am pretty sure I need to use some sort of proxy directive in the virtual host configuration for my local domain, but I am not having much luck so far.

I have enabled proxy_module and proxy_http_module. I am using the following in my virtual host configuration.

```
ProxyRequests On
<Proxy>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /loginscript https://externalserver.com/loginscript
ProxyPassReverse /loginscript https://externalserver.com/loginscript
```

I am getting a 500 server error when I use this. Error is "proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /loginscript. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

I have checked and the required modules are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off `ProxyRequests On`. If you haven't made any proxy restrictions, this turns your webserver into an open proxy, and that is **very** bad.
2. You are making an SSL reverse proxy (https:). Try adding `SSLProxyEngine On` to your vhost above the `ProxyPass`. Check out the [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine) docs. You may need to set some of the other SSL Proxy directives depending on your certificates.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm not quite there but you've put me on the right track.